# Angular attr.data-target and attr.id not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying assign unique id to my bootstrap modal as it's being using ngFor. Following is my code.

```
<div class="container shadow lead-container" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="customId"> -------------------------> . Data-target is set to customId
  <div class="row text-left">
    ----------------------> Other Content goes here
  </div>
</div>

<!--Lead Popup-->
<div class="modal fade" [attr.id]="customId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true"> -----------> [attr.id] is set to customid
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="container popup-container">
          <div class="row text-left">

             -------------------------------------> Modal Content Goes Here 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Following is my **component.ts**:

```
import { Lead } from './../models/lead';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lead',
  templateUrl: './lead.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lead.component.css']
})
export class LeadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public lead: Lead;
  @Input() public index;
  public customId: string;


  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customId = "custom".concat(this.index);
  }

}
```

When i click on div. The modal doesnt popup for some reason. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `[id]="customId"`

Comment: Can you please eloborate? I am new to angular

Comment: @JoelJoseph dint work tried it

Comment: have you pass the data of index

Comment: I am setting the customId in ngOnInit(). And i am passing the data for index

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jf3jis `<app-lead [index]="99"></app-lead>`

Comment: Yea I am doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add "#" to the id.

[attr.data-target]="'#'+customId"

Comment: With Bootstrap 5 it looks like this: ```[attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapseExample-' + i"``` for a collapse.